# Java - exception with invoke

Tags: java, libgdx, invoke

I added a new parameter into my game (libGDX) and I got a strange error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.game.game.GameLaunching.<init>(GameLaunching.java:21)
    at com.game.game.Main.main(Main.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I get this error when I try to use **thm**. With other parameter everything is ok.
Code:

```
 public class GameLaunching extends Game
{
    public boolean isPause = false;
    public boolean music, sound;
    public String flag;
    public String thm;
    public int scoreForShop;
    public boolean isFailture;

    public GameLaunching(String flag, String thm, boolean music, boolean sound)
    {
        Gdx.app.info("1", thm); // error
        this.flag = flag;
        this.music = music;
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        isPause = false;
        setScreen(new GameSurface(this));
    }
```

Code of Main class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "Game";
        cfg.width = 800;
        cfg.height = 480;

        new LwjglApplication(new GameLaunching("8","night", false, true), cfg);
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Where is the code for the Main class `at com.game.game.Main.main(Main.java:15)` ?

Comment: It's second piece of code with void main

Comment: I suspect that `Gdx.app` is `null`.

Comment: @QueMonster - Which is the 15th line in the Main class ?

Comment: new LwjglApplication(new GameLaunching("8","night", false, true), cfg).... error in "night"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move `Gdx.app.info("1", thm); // error` this line next to `new LwjglApplication(new GameLaunching("8","night", false, true), cfg);` in your main method

Reason being in Libgdx, the initialization of the library isn't complete until just before the start of the create method (which will be invoked by the Libgdx infrastructure to indicate that your app has started up), so you cannot access Gdx. until then.